# Does swimlane ngx-datatable has a sorting data accessor like in angular material table?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

In my code i need to use ngx-datatable. The row data is in key value pairs but value is of type object. Now the default sorting is not working. In case of angular Mat-Table its dataSource has a property called sortingDataAccessor which specifies the data with which the objects is to be sorted as objects cant be sorted. Does ngx-dataTable has any such functionality? If no, is there any workaround for that. As sorting is very much needed.

tableData format [{row11:{xxx:yyy,aaa:bbb},row12:{xxx:yyy,aaa:bbb}}]

Thank you.
Please help guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a custom Comparator available in ngx-datatable
please refer to their exaple https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#comparator-sorting

With this you can sort according to your need.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your answer and will report back.

Comment: Hii.. 
custom comparator is working. But the table does not get updated, the dataRows too. Why is it happening so?
The way i do is by rendering a widget in column cell with cdkPortal directive. Is it because of so?